# How many unit squares can overlap a given unit square without overlapping each other?

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, rectangles

> How many unit squares can overlap a given unit square without overlapping each other?

@calculus has managed to arrange 7 squares (see [this GeogebraTube page](http://tube.geogebra.org/student/m434279)). This seems like the maximum possible, but how to prove it formally?

Comment: Have you tried putting the seventh square in the middle of the configuration, rather than round the outside?

Comment: You can put the seventh in the middle, since the diagonal is of greater length than the sides. There is space enough. The optimal configuration of overlapping is to be tangent.

Comment: 7 squares are possible: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3852/a4wm5vz6_jpg.htm

Comment: @calculus Thanks! Now this seems absolutely full. But how can you prove that 8 are not possible?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi That is the difficulty of this problem. At the moment I have no idea how to prove it. But there is a great chance, that someone else have an idea.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but it sounds like the kissing number problem. Here is the similar question for non-overlapping squares from mathoverflow. Perhaps it inspire an idea as to the proof.         http://mathoverflow.net/questions/117579/the-kissing-number-of-a-square-cube-hypercube

Comment: Come to think of it couldn't you take the kissing number which proven to be 8 and then show that the overlapping number(which number what im calling the number in question) should be alteast or maybe even exactly one less, because that maybe the only decision that is possible in a situation- I dont know the technical term for that.

Comment: @Red the connection with the Kissing number is interesting, thanks! I hope you or someone else can formalize it.

Comment: @Red the general relation between the kissing number and the overlapping number is interesting and I asked a separate question about it: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/214629/kissing-number-and-overlapping-number

In any case, I don't think the difference is always one. For example, if we look at the family of axis-parallel unit-squares, the kissing-number is 8 but the overlapping-number is 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently $8$ squares are possible. Start with the example suggested by Peter Woolfitt and try to pack everything as tightly as possible.

In the following picture, each white square is tilted with respect to the gray square by a multiple of $\frac{\pi}{8}$ and the intersections are the obvious ones, i.e. each two squares intersect either in a whole side or in a single point.

[image]

Now perturb the angles and positions slightly so that the overlapping conditions are satisfied.

[image]

---

In case someone wants to play with this example, here is the *Mathematica* code used to produce the pictures. First, some useful functions:

```
ClearAll[A, T, sq]
A[phi_] := {{Cos[phi], -Sin[phi]}, {Sin[phi], Cos[phi]}}
T = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}};
sq[v_, phi_] := Line[Table[A[phi].t + v, {t, T}]]
```

The first picture:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.2], Polygon[T], Opacity[1], Gray, sq[{0, 0}, 0], 
  Black, sq[{0, 0}, 3 Pi/4], sq[{0, 0}, 5 Pi/4], sq[{0, 1}, 5 Pi/8], 
  sq[{0, 1}, Pi/8], sq[{1, 0}, -Pi/8], sq[{1, 0}, -5 Pi/8], 
  sq[{1, 1}, 0], sq[{1/2, (1 - Sqrt[2])/2} - {0.1, 0.1}, Pi/4]}]
```

The perturbation:

```
Graphics[{Opacity[0.2], Polygon[T], Opacity[1], Gray, sq[{0, 0}, 0], 
  Black, sq[{0, 0} + {0.01, 0.02}, 3 Pi/4], sq[{0, 0} + {0.02, 0.01}, 5 Pi/4], 
  sq[{0, 1} + {0.01, -0.01}, 5 Pi/8 - 0.05], sq[{0, 1} + {0.03, -0.01}, Pi/8 - 0.05], 
  sq[{1, 0} + {-0.01, 0.03}, -Pi/8 + 0.05], sq[{1, 0} + {-0.01, 0.01}, -5 Pi/8 + 0.05], 
  sq[{1, 1} - {0.01, 0.01}, 0], sq[{1/2, (1 - Sqrt[2])/2} - {0.12, 0.12}, Pi/4]}]
```

Comment: Is it possible to prove that more than 8 squares are impossible?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: I'll think about it and if I find a proof, I'll expand the answer.

Comment: Very nicely done!

Answer (score 9):

*This is a comment, but too large to fit in the comments section*

Pure area arguments are unlikely to work as shown by this near miss for $8$ squares:

[image: squares]